# How can I use set methods to set data field?

Tags: java

In one class, I am defining a setX method

```
public class Point{
int x;
int y;
...

public int setX(int x){
this.x = x;
}

...
}
```

And in another class, I need to create a point object and set its x field to be 1, I do not know what to write. This is what I write

```
public class Lab1{
 public static void main (String[] args){
Point a;

a.x = new setX(1);
...
 }
}
```

what should I do?

Comment: You cannot use `new` with a `method`. You need `class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should write like this.

```
class Point{
    int x;
    int y;

    public void setX(int x){
         this.x = x;
    }

    public int getX(){
        return this.x;
    }
}



public class Lab1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point A = new Point();
        A.setX(1);      
        System.out.println(A.getX());

    }
}
```

Comment: This is  perfect. NJU rocks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize `Point a;` try putting `Point a = new Point()` you should then be able to set it's x this should be your code.

```
public class Lab1{
public static void main (String[] args){
Point a = new Point();

a.setX(1);
System.out.println(a.x);//the value 1 should be displayed
}
```

If you would like to know what you class would look like with a constructor here is an example

```
public class Point{
int x;
int y;

public Point(int x, int y){
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
}

public void setX(int x){
this.x = x;
}

public void setY(int y){
this.y = y;
}

public int getX(){
return this.x;
}

}

public int getY(){
return this.y
}
```

Comment: This is much more than I want. Thank you, Sir.

Answer (score 2):

Setters should be VOID since they don't return any values...right?  Because they only SET instance variables

```
public void setX(int x){
  this.x = x;
}
```

In your Point class you should have a constructor right?  Which you can create new objects from the class Point.

How do you do that?

Like so:

`Point someName = new Point(<SOME INT HERE>);`

**Set Value with Constructor...not your example**

```
public class Lab1 {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Point a = new Point(5);
    }
}
```

**Your Solution**

```
public class Lab1 {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Point a = new Point();
        a.setX(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, after I get the setters right. What should I do next to set its x field?

Comment: This is true it actually looks like there are a few things wrong with the code.

Comment: If you look at my answer it looks like you are trying to set a value to an uninitalized object

Comment: He doesn't have a constructor so he can't put new Point(5) he would need to create a constructor to allow for that first.

Comment: Like I said he SHOULD have a constructor.  I see ..... in his question which lets me assume he is not showing everything in his point class.

Comment: Yeah that's true but judging by his difficulty with this he may not even know what a constructor is.

Comment: Lol I added your reccomendation to my code and +1 your answer for helping me formulate mine :D

Comment: *"Setters should be VOID"* except when they are part of a factory or builder (for example), then returning a reference to the object is always helpful, then you can get method chaining to work, like `StringBuilder` for example - but that might be beyond the scope of the question ;)

Comment: @CodyAnderson I know a little about constructor, I am taking both Java Database and Introduction to Java at the same time, I have no choice, my university only provide database once per year. Thank you, now I understand Java more and your answer will help many frustrated beginners like me.